# postgres user has no access to public schema

Tags: postgresql, permissions, sql-grant

I am getting the following error on postgresql 12:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
```

even though I am logged in as `postgres` (who is superuser), and I have granted all on the schema, and on all the tables:

```
GRANT all ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
grant all on all tables in schema "public" to postgres;
```

And `postgres` is superuser:

```
=# \duS+
                                                                            List of roles
         Role name         |                         Attributes                         |                          Member of                           | Description 
---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
 postgres                  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}                                                           |
```

When checking the grants, it looks like I should have `INSERT` privileges:

```
 SELECT *                                                                                               
  FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
 WHERE grantee ='postgres' and table_name='wms_zone';
 grantor  | grantee  | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | privilege_type | is_grantable | with_hierarchy 
----------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------
 sapphire | postgres | table1        | public       | wms_zone   | TRIGGER        | YES          | NO
 sapphire | postgres | table1        | public       | wms_zone   | REFERENCES     | YES          | NO
 sapphire | postgres | table1        | public       | wms_zone   | TRUNCATE       | YES          | NO
 sapphire | postgres | table1        | public       | wms_zone   | DELETE         | YES          | NO
 sapphire | postgres | table1        | public       | wms_zone   | UPDATE         | YES          | NO
 sapphire | postgres | table1        | public       | wms_zone   | SELECT         | YES          | YES
 sapphire | postgres | table1        | public       | wms_zone   | INSERT         | YES          | NO
```

**Update** INSERTing into another table in the same database and schema does work.

Comment: Are you sure `postgres` role still has the `Superuser` attribute? What's `\duS+` showing in psql?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that it's possible to rename `postgres` role to something else and create a regular role of that name, without the `superuser` attribute. The bootstrap role that does have to have this attribute, doesn't necessarily have to be named `postgres`, leaving the name to be used freely. If your `postgres` was in fact a `superuser`, they shouldn't be checked for privileges of any kind except for login.

Comment: Another possibility is that you issued (accidentally or through client initial query config) a `set role not_postgres;` making it so that even though you were connected as `postgres`, from that point you were acting as `not_postgres` role. `select current_user;` should clarify that.

Comment: @Zegarek Yes, `postgres` is superuser. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly *why* this causes this weird behaviour, but the problem was in the ownership of the tables.

This particular table had a foreign key set on a table that was not owned by `postgres` (it had all permissions though).

Setting all objects to the `postgres` owner made it work:

```
 REASSIGN OWNED BY olduser TO postgres
```

Comment: When checking foreign key constraints, the real user checks them as the owner of the table, which might mean temporarily giving up its super powers.  So even a superuser can get permission errors in such cases.  The complete error message should have contained more info which would have made this more clear.

Comment: I understand, but the user had all permissions on the foreign table as well.

Comment: The error says it was lacking access on the schema, not the table itself, so that is compatible with your observation.  You can get into this state if the schema access was revoked after the table was already created, or maybe if the table ownership was changed by a superuser.